# C# Exception Debugging - How to go back and resume exception line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In the good old days of VB6 when debugging an error I would temporarily type Resume within an error handler to take me back to the line which had caused the error.

Is there a way to do the same thing in C#? I am not talking about a permanent way to go back, this is just when you are debugging and you want to know which line caused the exception which you are currently in the catch statement for.

So just to be clear.

1. I know something is causing an exception so I put a break point on the catch statement
2. The debugger hits the break point in the catch, I want to know which line caused it and take the debugger back to it.

I can't use the Debug > Options - throw on all exceptions as there are other exceptions in the app silently occurring (I didn't write it).

Thanks

Comment: If there are other exceptions being thrown, you can limit what thrown exceptions execution stops on to just the exception you're trying to catch.

Comment: Each exception has a stack trace with filenames and line numbers if the pdb files exist. Can't you just use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace in the exception will tell you what line it occurred on. You can then drag the yellow arrow back up to that line and resume debugging from there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to continue stepping out of the catch statement, then you can "Set Next Statement" or drag the yellow arrow up to the beginning of the try statement.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would probably to put a breakpoint at the beginning of the try block, if you then step through that block it will show you where the error is.

Alternatively, remove the try and catch temporarily and visual studio will halt execution at the line that threw the exception because the exception won't be caught.